# Unexpected token "const [xxx, setXxx] = useState"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a project with React and Django to allow users to sign up and log in.

Whenenver I run my project (with `npm start`) though, I keep getting this error:

```
./src/components/signup_components/Signup.js
  Line 15:11:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  13 |         err:null
  14 |     }
> 15 |     const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
     |           ^
  16 |     const [password1, setPassword1] = useState('');
  17 |     const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
  18 |     const [errors,setErrors] = useState(false);
```

Here's my code:

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component,useState,useEffect } from "react";
import secure_login from "../../assets/images/secure_login.svg"
import "../../assets/scss/core/signup_components/_signup.scss"

export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('token') !==null) {
            window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/profile');
        } else {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }, []);

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    const user = {
        email: email,
        password: password
    };

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
        .then(res => console.log(res.json()))
        .then(data => {
            if(data.key) {
                localStorage.clear();
                localStorage.setItem('token',data.key);
                window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/profile');
            } else {
                setEmail('');
                setPassword('');
                localStorage.clear();
                setErrors(true);
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
    return (
      <div className="base-container" ref={this.props.containerRef}>
        <div className="header">Login</div>
        <div className="content">
          <div className="image">
            <img src={secure_login} />
          </div>
          <div className="form">
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
              <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="footer">
          <button type="button" className="btn">
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Signup.js**

```
import React, { Component,useState,useEffect } from "react";
import secure_signup from "../../assets/images/secure_signup.svg"
import CountrySelector from './CountryList'
import ProcessImage from 'react-imgpro';


export default class Signup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    state= {
        src:'',
        err:null
    }
    const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password1, setPassword1] = useState('');
    const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
    const [errors,setErrors] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
            window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/profile');
        } else {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }, []);

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const user = {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            location: location
        };

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/profiles/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                if(data.key) {
                    localStorage.clear();
                    localStorage.setItem('token',data.key);
                    window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/profile');
                } else {
                    setEmail('');
                    setPassword1('')
                    setLocation('')
                    localStorage.clear();
                    setErrors(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
      render() {
        return (
            <div className="base-container" ref={this.props.containerRef}>
                {loading === false && <div className="header">Register</div> }
                {errors === true && <h2>Cannot signup with provided credentials</h2>}
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="image">
                        <ProcessImage
                            image={secure_signup}
                            resize={{ width:400, height: 400 }}
                            processedImage={(src,err) => this.setState({ src,err})}
                            />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="name"
                                placeholder="name"
                                value={name}
                                onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                required
                            />{' '}
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="email"
                                placeholder="email"
                                value={email}
                                onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                required
                            />{' '}
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="location">Location</label>
                            <CountrySelector />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="password"
                                placeholder="password"
                                value={password}
                                onChange={e => setPassword1(e.target.value)}
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div className="footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={onSubmit}>
                    Register
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppRoute from './utils/AppRoute';
import ScrollReveal from './utils/ScrollReveal';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import Login from './components/login_components/Login';
import Signup from './components/signup_components/Signup'
import Profile from './components/profile_components/Profile'

// Layouts
import LayoutDefault from './layouts/LayoutDefault';

// Views 
import Home from './views/Home';

// Initialize Google Analytics
ReactGA.initialize(process.env.REACT_APP_GA_CODE);

const trackPage = page => {
  ReactGA.set({ page });
  ReactGA.pageview(page);
};

const App = () => {

  const childRef = useRef();
  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const page = location.pathname;
    document.body.classList.add('is-loaded')
    childRef.current.init();
    trackPage(page);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <ScrollReveal
      ref={childRef}
      children={() => (
        <Switch>
          <AppRoute exact path="/" component={Home} layout={LayoutDefault} />
          <AppRoute exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <AppRoute exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <AppRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </Switch>
      )} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

I don't get where the unexpected token error is coming from. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Hooks (functions starting with `use`) should **only be used in functional components**. You already declared state, use `this.state.property` and `this.setState` instead. The reason you're getting the error is because you can't declare variables like that inside a class.

Comment: Do you mind adding that as an answer? @code

Answer (score 1):

Before I correct your error, your implementation first needs some fixing. (All your problems originate from `Signup.js`.)

The concept of React hooks (any function starting with `use`) was invented to allow [React functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) to do things that used to be only able to be done with class components, for example, in class components you might write (in the constructor):

```js
this.state = {
  name: "John",
  age: 23
};
```

To access the state:

```js
this.state.name // <-- "John"
```

Then to modify the state you do:

```js
this.setState({ ...this.state, age: 292 });
```

Setting the state causes the component to rerender and modifies the UI as such.

To do this in functional components, there's a built-in hook called `useState`, used something like (inside your functional component):

```js
const [name, setName] = useState("John");
const [age, setAge] = useState(23);
```

To access the state's name, you simply do:

```js
name // <-- "John"
```

and to modify it:

```js
setName("Jane");
```

So the problem with your code is that you're trying to use hooks for class components, which already has those built in features. You got it right when you wrote:

```js
state = {
  src: "",
  err: null
}
```

Now, you have the task of moving everything else into that state declaration:

```js
state = {
  src: "",
  err: null,
  email: "",
  password1: "",
  location: "",
  errors: false,
  loading: true
}
```

And to access the state you'd do:

```js
this.state.password1 // <-- ""
```

or

```js
this.state.loading // true
```

And to set the state:

```js
this.setState({ ...this.state, loading: false, password: "e34O#*Nre" });
```

You're also using the `useEffect` hook. Change that to `componentDidMount() {...}`.

However, in `App.js` you are creating a functional component, so everything works just fine.

*Now for your error...*
There are 2 ways to declare class-scoped variables (and your way isn't one of them):

1. Inside any class method (generally in the constructor), declare it with `this.variableName = value`
2. Outside of all class methods, declare it with `variableName = value`

In both ways of declaration they are read with `this.variableName`.

So that's why JavaScript complained at you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with my project, then figure it out.

I am not sure about this information but it seems `useState('')` not working with class component it just work with functional component.

Try to change your > Signup component to functional component, just do the following:

```
 `import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";
    import secure_signup from "../../assets/images/secure_signup.svg"
    import CountrySelector from './CountryList'
    import ProcessImage from 'react-imgpro';
    
    
    const Signup = () => {
        
                // PASS YOUR VARIABLES HERE
                 
            return (

                // TYPE YOUR CODE HERE
          );
        
    }`
```